# How to remark inputs? HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, angular

[image]

I made a login form, but the inputs look like this, how could I underline the frames of the inputs?
Html:

```
  <div class="center">
    <form #f [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
      <img id="user" class="user" [src]="photo">
      <div class="messagebox-container">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input
            matInput
            formControlName="username"
            type="text"
            placeholder="e-mail"
          />
      </div>

      <div>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input
          matInput
          formControlName="password"
          type={{typePass}}
          id="password"
          name="password"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="contraseña"
          [attr.disabled]="loading ? '' : null"
          />
        </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you checked if the module where this component belongs is importing MatInputModule from @angular/material/input? Sometimes I get issues like this one when I miss it.

you can check the documentation [here](https://v9.material.angular.io/components/input/api)